# Importing 3D background to a 3D design software

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, 3d, cad

We have the following task: we would like to take a 3D image of a natural background where someone wants to build a camping.

We then would like to import this image and draw into it the 3D buildings of the imagined camping.

Is there a good open source program we could use for this?

Comment: What OS should the program run on? And in case it comes to a paid solution (yes, that can also be the case with open source – and you didn't specify "free of charge"), how much you'd be willing to spend? Further, what format(s) must be supported? The better you describe your needs, the better can answers made fitting them.

Comment: Windows. And, I meant open source as not having to pay. I added "windows" and "gratis" labels to make this clear.

Comment: IN my answer I gave Blender as an all round solution. But if you wanted a free, open source more CAD program, I have tried a few from Sourceforge. There's BRL CAD at [BRL](https://brlcad.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking is to do compositing. Blender can do compositing; [compositing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/index.html) 
Blender is also free and opensource.